# Python BeautifulSoup inconsistent result

Tags: python

I have been trying to learn a bit of python, and I tried to create a small program that asks the user for subreddit and then prints all the front page headlines and links to the articles, here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

subreddit = input('Type de subreddit you want to see : ')
link_visit = f'https://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/'
print(link_visit)

base_url = link_visit
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for article in soup.find_all('div', class_='top-matter'):

   headline = article.find('p', class_='title')
   print('HeadLine : ' , headline.text )

   a = headline.find('a', href=True)
   link = a['href'].split('/domain')
   print('Link : ' , link[0])
```

My problem is that sometimes it prints the desired result, other times it does nothing, only asks the user for the subrredit and prints the link to said subreddit.

Can someone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Do you get inconsistent results when repeating the same input?

Comment: Yes, for example the worldnews subreddit. Sometimes I get all the headlines and links to the articles, other times I get nothing.

Comment: Have you thought about using `PRAW`? It's the Python Reddit API Wrapper, you can find the repo [here](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw).

Comment: Never heard of that, is that required to my program?

Comment: Not required, but _very_ recommended. Because as you can tell by @Rob answer Reddit will limit you to requests. So go to your Reddit account (or create one, its free) and get an API key. Then start using `PRAW`.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is being rejected by reddit in order to conserve their resources.

When you detect the failing case, print out the HTML. I think you'll see something like this:

```html
    <h1>whoa there, pardner!</h1>



<p>we're sorry, but you appear to be a bot and we've seen too many requests
from you lately. we enforce a hard speed limit on requests that appear to come
from bots to prevent abuse.</p>

<p>if you are not a bot but are spoofing one via your browser's user agent
string: please change your user agent string to avoid seeing this message
again.</p>

<p>please wait 3 second(s) and try again.</p>

    <p>as a reminder to developers, we recommend that clients make no
    more than <a href="http://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API">one
    request every two seconds</a> to avoid seeing this message.</p>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but how can I do that?